# Github prompting for credentials after ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh, debian

I established ssh with github as instructed here:

https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

I tested the ssh connection, but still no luck

```
iron@debian:~/Documents/websites/basic_setup_edited_20-08-2017@21-15$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi alex3wielki! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But after doing git push I get this:

```
iron@debian:~/Documents/websites/basic_setup_edited_20-08-2017@21-15$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com': alex3wielki
Password for 'https://alex3wielki@github.com':
```

I tried switching the

`url = https://github.com/alex3wielki/project-setup.git`

to

`url = ssh://github.com/alex3wielki/project-setup.git`

as instructed in another post, but all it did was:

```
iron@debian:~/Documents/websites/basic_setup_edited_20-08-2017@21-15$ git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know the repo exists, here's the link

https://github.com/alex3wielki/project-setup

When I change the repo link to

```
url = ssh://git@github.com/alex3wielki/project-setup.git
```

it doesn't prompt for password, but even after doing a change and going `git add .` I get

```
Everything up-to-date
```

I'm using Debian 9. What am I missing?

Here is some more info

SSH "works"

[image: SSH "works"]

But not really

[image: But not really]

I am in the root/top of the folder structure. `git add .` and `git push` are done from here

```
iron@debian:~/Documents/websites/basic_setup_edited_20-08-2017@21-15$ ls -a
.  ..  assets  bower.json  .bowerrc  content  _dev  .git  Gruntfile.js  index.html  node_modules  package.json  .sass-cache  scripts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your ssh key to github, so that github knows that you are the only one how is pushing to the repo.
You can learn how to create ssh key and add it to github [here](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh//)

### Generating the ssh key

1. In terminal

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Enter the desired passphrase and other information asked during the process.

### Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent

First Start the ssh agent

`eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

Add your private key to ssh agent

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

### Adding your key to github

For addign your key to github you can follow the processs mentioned [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

Comment: Ok, I put it wrong. They're already there. The whole setup from this link is done. It even says on github that the key was used this week, meanwhile the repo I'm trying to push to was "last updated" 16 days ago. I'd add screenshots, but I'm new to Debian and not sure where the screenshots go

Comment: You can find the screenshot in picture folder
located at

`/home/<user>/picture`

Comment: `git add .` will only work well if you are at root location, otherwise, it can miss some of the files....can you confirm this.

Comment: I am in the top of the folder structure. I can add a screenshot from tree if you want

Comment: Can you again do the changes and use `git status` before dong `git add`.
`git status` will list all the modified files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153725/discussion-between-ajinkya-dhote-and-alex3wielki).